# Azure Sentinel Workbook Displays Old Data Due To Caching

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have created a KQL and using that plotted a Tile view in the workbook. The data in the Tile is supposed to change based on the Timerange filter I have added. This is working fine unless new events are received. So let's say I have selected "Last 24 hours" at 12 PM and the count in tile is "2". Now I keep the session idle for a few minutes and at 12:10 PM, a new event arrives. Thereafter when I change the Timerange filter to "Last 5 minutes", I see the new event, but when I again change the Timerange filter to "Last 24 hours", the count still will be "2" instead of "3".

However, when I refresh the entire web page, the count will be updated. Is there any way to overcome this? I think the results are being cached by Azure and reused, but is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

Thank to [John Gardner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13687/john-gardner) for helping answering this query on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1bb873b-089d-4da8-b322-6a4599b88a3e/azure-sentinel-workbook-displays-old-data-due-to-caching?forum=opinsights). Resurfacing the same answer for broader community here.

Workbooks does do local caching of queries, of which items in the cache will live several minutes. Backend services may also cache results.

If you explicitly refresh a query and bypass any caching, you should manually re-run the query via the "run query" button in edit mode, or use the refresh button in the workbooks toolbar, both of which force a query to be refreshed.

Additional [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-overview#dashboard-time-ranges) around autorefresh on the dashboard using a time range parameter.

Hope the above information helps. Thank you

Comment: @Utsav Patel - Can you please review and revert back for any questions you might have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested to make sure it's not the web browser caching the content? Try running the Workbook in an inPrivate Window to test.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, I'm new to the platform and I can't find any documentation but Azure sentinel workbook is to visualize realtime data than isn't there any azure facility where we can disable this kind of mechanism.